# Referring linked resource from eclipse rcp

Tags: java, resources, rcp

I  have created a linked resource inside a plugin where the resource is sitting in some other folder.
Some how i want to use this link resource in my plugin .But when i tried to get bundle and file url in below mentioned way it is returning me null as only link is there in the plugin and actual resource is sitting some where else.

```
 Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("xxxx");
    Path path = new Path("resource");
    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
    URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

Any clue on this will be  helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `IFile`:

```
 IPath path = new Path("path in the workspace");

 IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);

 IPath actualPath = file.getLocation();
```

Comment: I tied to use your methodology but still the actual path is coming null i have no idea what i ma doing wrong ..

Comment: Is this resource inside a plugin jar or in the workspace? My code only works for resources in the runtime workspace. I don't think links in a plugin jar are going to work at all.